# What is the difference between ( command1 command2 ) and ( command1; command2)?

Tags: bash

What is the difference between `( command1 command2 )` and `( command1; command2)`?
Anyone could give some detail explanation for this. Here is my test result:

```
( a=3; echo $a) #the result is 3
```

but

```
( a=3 echo $a) #the result shows nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a=3; echo $a` is two commands. `a=3 echo $a` is one command (it is obvious that it cannot be two commands since you can't say `echo foo echo bar` and expect the two commands to evaluate correctly), which evaluates a command in an environment where `a=3`. Bash manual defines this syntax under "Simple commands":

> A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator.

The important bit is the order: the variable substitution is the first thing that occurs; then prefixed assignment will change the sub-environment; then the command is evaluated.

In detail: the first one, `a=3; echo $a` will

1) evaluate `a=3` and insert binding `a=3` in current environment

2) evaluate `echo $a` by substituting the current environment variables, obtain `echo 3`, then output `3`.

The second one is a bit more complex. `a=3 echo $a`, being a single command, will

1) evaluate `a=3 echo $a` by substituting the current environment variables. Since `a` is not defined, we obtain `a=3 echo ""`. It then makes a new environment where `a=3`, and evaluates `echo ""` there.

It is easier to see if we switch the command to be `a=3 bash -c 'echo $a'`. Since `$a` is single-quoted, it will not be evaluated, so the command will run `bash -c 'echo $a'` in the environment where `a=3`. `bash` will then evaluate its command, `echo $a`, in its environment, which will now include `a=3`, obtain `echo 3`, and print 3.

It is interesting to contrast it with `a=3 bash -c "echo $a"`. Since `$a` is double-quoted, it will be evaluated; the command becomes `bash -c 'echo ""'`, which is then evaluated in a sub-environment where `a=3`, printing an empty line.

Another difference is that `a=3 echo $a` runs `echo` in a sub-environment where `a=3`, but after that line `a` is back to being undefined (or having whatever value it had before). In `a=3; echo $a`, the current environment is permanently changed, and `$a` will be `3` until changed again.